# How to fix SSO connect with cefSharp offline browser to webserver hosted by self-signed PC?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, cefsharp

**TL;DR:** I am grasping for straws here, anybody got a SSO with CefSharp working and can point me to what I am doing wrong? I try to connect to a SSL-SSO page through CefSharp but it wont work - neither does it in Chrome-Browser. With IE it *just works*. I added the to trusted sites (Proxy/Security), I tried to tried to whitelist-policy the URL for chrome in the registry and tried different CefSharp settings - nothing helped.

---

I am trying (to no avail) to connect to a SSO enabled page via `CefSharp-Offline`-browsing.

**Browsing with normal IE it *just works*:**

- I get 302 answer
- the redirected site gives me a 401 (Unauthorized) with `NTLM, Negotiate`
- IE automagically sends the `NTLM Auth` and receives a `NTLM WWW-Authenticate`
- after some more 302 it ends in 200 and a logged in state on the website

**Browsing with Chrome 69.0.3497.100 fails:**

[image: not secure]

I guess this is probably due to the fact that the webserver is setup on a co-workers PC and uses a self-signed cert.

---

**F12-Debugging in IE/Chrome:**

- In IE I see a 302, followed by two 401 answers, and end on the logged in site.
- In chrome I see only 302 and 200 answers and end on the "fallback" login site for user/pw entry.

The main difference in (one of the 302) request headers is `NEGOTIATE` vs `NTLM`

```
// IE:
Authorization: NTLM TlRMT***==

// Chrome:
Authorization: Negotiate TlRMT***==
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
DNT: 1
```

No luck to connect through CefSharp so far, I simply land in its `RequestHandler.GetAuthCredentials()` - I do not want to pass any credentials with that.

---

**What I tried to get it working inside Windows / Chrome:**

- installed the self-signed cert as "trusted certificate authorities"
- added the co-workers host to the Windows Internet Proxy settings as *trusted site*
- added the co-workers host to `Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\` registry as
- https://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AuthServerWhitelist
- https://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist

which all in all did nothing: I still do not get any SSO using Chrome:  [image: not secure]

---

**What I tried to get it working inside CefSharp:**

- deriving from  `CefSharp.Handler.DefaultRequestHandler`, overriding

  - `OnSelectClientCertificate` -> never gets called
  - `OnCertificateError` -> no longer gets called
  - `GetAuthCredentials` -> gets called, but I do not want to pass login credentials this way - I already have a working solution for the http:// case when calling the sites normal login-page.
- providing a settings object to `Cef.Initialize(...)` that contains

```
var settings = new CefSettings { IgnoreCertificateErrors = true, ... };
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add ("auth-server-whitelist", "*host-url*");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add ("auth-delegate-whitelist", "*host-url*");
```

- on creation of the browser providing a RequestContext:

```
var browser = new CefSharp.OffScreen.ChromiumWebBrowser (
    "", requestContext: CreateNewRequestContext (webContext.Connection.Name));
```

`CefSharp.RequestContext CreateNewRequestContext (string connName)
{
var subDirName = Helper.Files.FileHelper.MakeValidFileSystemName (connName);
var contextSettings = new RequestContextSettings
{
PersistSessionCookies = false,
PersistUserPreferences = false,
CachePath = Path.Combine (Cef.GetGlobalRequestContext ().CachePath, subDirName),
IgnoreCertificateErrors = true,
};
// ...
return new CefSharp.RequestContext (contextSettings);
}`

I am aware that part of those changes are redundant (f.e. 3 ways to set whitelists of which at least 2 should work for CefSharp, not sure about the registry one affecting it) and in case of `IgnoreCertificateErrors` dangerous and can't stay in. I just want it to work somehow to then trim back what to do to make it work in production.

---

Research:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecAuthN/microsoft-ntlm
- https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/http-authentication
- https://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=11085 leading to
- https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1150/ntlm-authentication-issue (fixed 2y ago)
- https://sysadminspot.com/windows/google-chrome-and-ntlm-auto-logon-using-windows-authentication/
- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/1594XUaOVKY/8ChGCBrwYUYJ

and others .. still none the wiser.

---

Question: I am grasping for straws here , anybody got a SSO with CefSharp working and can point me to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Were you able to get it working in `Chrome`? `CEF` appears to only support one method of whitelisting, see https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1150/ntlm-authentication-issue#comment-28338785

Comment: @amaitland No solution yet, And I got no notification for your comment - so sorry for being unresponsive. I'll post my solution If I happen to fix it somehow. I did the whitelisting using `settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add ("auth-server-whitelist", "*host-url*");` but that did not work out either.

Comment: It's my understanding you can only set the whitelist through `RequestContext.SetPreference`. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-context-browser-isolation You can set preferences for the global context in http://cefsharp.github.io/api/67.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IBrowserProcessHandler_OnContextInitialized.htm

Comment: Source for preference names: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/pref_names.cc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

**TL;DR:** I faced (at least) 2 problems: invalid SSL certificates and Kerberos token problems. My test setup has local computers set up with a web-server I call into. These local computers are mostly windows client OS VMs with self-signed certificates. Some are windows servers. The latter worked, the fromer not. With IE both worked.

---

Browsing to the site in question using `https://...` lead to CEFsharp encountering the self-signed certificate (which is not part of a trusted chain of certs) - therefore it will call the browsers [RequestHandler](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/RequestHandler.cs) (if set) and call into its

```
public override bool OnCertificateError (IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, 
                                         CefErrorCode errorCode, string requestUrl, 
                                         ISslInfo sslInfo, IRequestCallback callback)
{
  Log.Logger.Warn (sslInfo.CertStatus.ToString ());
  Log.Logger.Warn (sslInfo.X509Certificate.Issuer);

  if (CertIsTrustedEvenIfInvalid (sslInfo.X509Certificate))
  {
    Log.Logger.Warn ("Trusting: " + sslInfo.X509Certificate.Issuer);

    if (!callback.IsDisposed)
      using (callback)
      {
        callback?.Continue (true);
      }

    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return base.OnCertificateError (browserControl, browser, errorCode, requestUrl,
                                    sslInfo, callback);
  }
}
```

For testing purposes I hardcoded certain tests into `CertIsTrustedEvenIfInvalid (sslInfo.X509Certificate)` that would return `true` for my test environment - this might be replaced by a simple `return false`, an UI-Popup presenting the cert and asking the user if she wants to proceed or it might take certain user-provided cert-files into account - dunno yet:

```
bool CertIsTrustedEvenIfInvalid (X509Certificate certificate)
{
  var debug = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> (StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
  {
    ["cn"] = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { "some", "data" },
    ["ou"] = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { "other", "stuff" },
    ["o"] = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { "..." },
    ["l"] = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { "Atlantis" },
    ["s"] = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { "Outer Space" },
    ["c"] = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { "whatsnot" },
  };

  var x509issuer = certificate.Issuer
    .Split (",".ToCharArray ())
    .Select (part => part.Trim().Split("=".ToCharArray(), 2).Select (p => p.Trim()))
    .ToDictionary (t => t.First (), t => t.Last ());

  return x509issuer.All (kvp => debug.ContainsKey (kvp.Key) &&
                                debug[kvp.Key].Contains (kvp.Value));
}
```

---

Only if the SSL-Step works, SSO will be tried.

---

After solving the SSL issue at hand I ran into different behavious of Chrome versus IE/Firefox etc as described [here @ Choosing an authentication scheme](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/http-authentication)
 - the gist of it is:

- if multiple auth schemes are reported by the server, IE/Firefox use the first one they know - as delivered by the server (preference by order)
- Chrome uses the one which it deems of highest priority (in order: `Negotiate` -> `NTLM` -> `Digest`->`Basic`) ignoring the servers ordering of alternate schemes.

My servers reported `NTLM,Negotiante` (that order) - with IE it simply worked.

With Chrome this led to Kerberos tokens being exchanged - which only worked when the web-server was hosted on a Windows Server OS - not for Windows Client OS. Probably some kind of failed configuration for Client-OS computers in the AD used. Not sure though - but against Server OS it works.

Additionaly I implemented the

```
public override bool GetAuthCredentials (IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, 
                                         IFrame frame, bool isProxy, string host, 
                                         int port, string realm, string scheme, 
                                         IAuthCallback callback)
{
  // pseudo code - asks for user & pw 
  (string UserName, string Password) = UIHelper.UIOperation (() =>
  {
    // UI to ask for user && password: 
    // return (user,pw) if input ok else return (null,null)
  });

  if (UserName.IsSet () && Password.IsSet ())
  {
    if (!callback.IsDisposed)
    {
      using (callback)
      {
        callback?.Continue (UserName, Password);
      }
      return true;
    }
  }

  return base.GetAuthCredentials (browserControl, browser, frame, isProxy, 
                                  host, port, realm, scheme, callback);
}
```

to allow for a fail-back if the SSO did not work out. After providing the AD credentials in this dialog login is possible as well).

For good measure I also whitelisted the hosts to the CEF-Browser context on creation of a new broswer like so:

```
CefSharp.RequestContext CreateNewRequestContext (string subDirName, string host,
                                                 WebConnectionType conType)
{
  var contextSettings = new RequestContextSettings
  {
    PersistSessionCookies = false,
    PersistUserPreferences = false,
    CachePath = Path.Combine (Cef.GetGlobalRequestContext ().CachePath, subDirName),
  };

  var context = new CefSharp.RequestContext (contextSettings);

  if (conType == WebConnectionType.Negotiate) # just an enum for UserPW + Negotiate
    Cef.UIThreadTaskFactory.StartNew (() =>
     {
       // see https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/pref_names.cc  for names

       var settings = new Dictionary<string, string>
       {
         ["auth.server_whitelist"] = $"*{host}*",
         ["auth.negotiate_delegate_whitelist"] = $"*{host}*",
         // only set-able via policies/registry :/
         // ["auth.schemes"] = "ntlm" // "basic", "digest", "ntlm", "negotiate"
       };

       // set the settings - we *trust* the host with this and allow negotiation
       foreach (var s in settings)
         if (!context.SetPreference (s.Key, s.Value, out var error))
           Log.Logger.Debug?.Log ($"Error setting '{s.Key}': {error}");
     });

  return context;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to create a new RequestContext, you can change the global one if you like see http://cefsharp.github.io/api/67.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IBrowserProcessHandler_OnContextInitialized.htm this method is called on the UI thread, so you don't need to switch threads.

Comment: @amaitland I have different browser objects with different request contexts that own different login cookies etc. using one global one still possible with that? the created request context of the method is injected into the browser.-contstuctor

Comment: For your use case no, you'll have to use different request contexts. You could use http://cefsharp.github.io/api/67.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IRequestContextHandler_OnRequestContextInitialized.htm